# RxJava wait for boolean(condition)

Tags: java, rx-java

There is method `updateFromRemote()`:

```
public class WorkshiftSettingsDaoImpl implements WorkshiftSettingsDao {

    private boolean isUpdating = false;

    public Observable<WorkshiftSettings> updateFromRemote() {
        return remoteDataStore.get()
                .retryWhen(RxOperatorsHelpers::retryWhenAnyIoExceptionWithDelay)
                .doOnSubscribe(this::setUpdatingStarted)
                .doOnUnsubscribe(this::setUpdatingFinished)
                .flatMap(workshiftSettings -> localDataStore.put(workshiftSettings));
    }

    private void setUpdatingStarted() {
        if(isUpdating) throw new RuntimeException("already updating");
        isUpdating = true;
    }

    private void setUpdatingFinished() {
        if(!isUpdating) throw new RuntimeException("already finished");
        isUpdating = false;
    }

}
```

How can I implement this behavior:

if `isUpdating == true` then wait until it will be changed to `false` and execute presented chain.

if `isUpdating == false` then just execute presented chain.

There is my solution:

```
public Observable<WorkshiftSettings> updateFromRemote() {
    Observable<WorkshiftSettings> updateRemoveDataObservable =  remoteDataStore.get()
            .retryWhen(RxOperatorsHelpers::retryWhenAnyIoExceptionWithDelay)
            .doOnSubscribe(this::setUpdatingStarted)
            .doOnUnsubscribe(this::setUpdatingFinished)
            .flatMap(workshiftSettings -> localDataStore.put(workshiftSettings));

    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        while (isUpdating) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        return null;
    }).concatMap(o -> updateRemoveDataObservable);
}
```

But I think there is something wrong :)

Any better idea?

Comment: Is it a hard requirement that you act on the change of isUpdating, or is it possible to add a setUpdating method? If you can the you could call `onNext` on a `Subject` object from setUpdating, and merge the subject with your Observable.

Comment: `isUpdating` changed by `setUpdatingStarted()`/`setUpdatingFinished()`. I edited my question to include them.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, did i get correctly your flow. But i guess you have some "place" where `isUpdating` is changed. 
If yes, you can just create 
`final BehaviorSubject<Boolean> isUpdatingSubject = BehaviorSubject.<Boolean>create()` 
and in this "place", instead of changing boolean variable, you do:
 `isUpdatingSubject.onNext(false)`

And

```
public Observable<WorkshiftSettings> updateFromRemote() {
    return isUpdatingSubject
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .filter(new Func1<Boolean, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(BookingErrorActivity isUpdating) {
                    return !isUpdating;
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<Object, Observable<WorkshiftSettings>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<WorkshiftSettings> call(Object o) {
                    return remoteDataStore.get()
                            .retryWhen(RxOperatorsHelpers::retryWhenAnyIoExceptionWithDelay)
                            .doOnSubscribe(this::setUpdatingStarted)
                            .doOnUnsubscribe(this::setUpdatingFinished)
                            .flatMap(workshiftSettings -> localDataStore.put(workshiftSettings));
                }
            });

}
```

But be carefule: with such solution this Observable will emit each time, when `isUpdatingSubject` emits `true`, so it can be not cool sometimes. 
To prevent from it you can use `.first()` before `flatMap()`

**PS** You can read more about [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html)

**PSS** Sorry, i used to java7 syntax

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but I meant something else. `isUpdating` changed by `WorkshiftSettingsDaoImpl` itself. See updated question.

Comment: Okay, i guess you need `.debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, uiScheduler)`

Comment: Okay, i guess you need something like: `.debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, uiScheduler).withLatestFrom(isUpdatingSubject, [secondParam]).filter([isFalse])`